# EXCEL - retrieve value of specific cell in column based off of date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My question is as follows:

I have an excel workbook with two worksheets.  The first worksheet has my bills listed in rows, and paydates in columns.  The second worksheet has a weekly cashflow plan with spots corresponding to various bills in the first.

I would like the cash flow worksheet to update the cell to the dollar value of the bill if its due.  I have attached a link to my box with the excel file. Screen shots are below as well.  In the screenshot examples, for instance, i would like the Electricity Cell in Cash flow sheet to Show $238 since the Electricity in the Bills sheet for the current week has an X in that location.

[Excel Workbook](https://app.box.com/s/o10nu3ac7vm0wb0yoboet9lwq1qyophk)

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Bills Sheet]
[image: Cash Flow Sheet]

Comment: Are u using interop.Excel.dll for excel operation in your project?

Comment: no idea what that is to be honest, just using formulas to calculate everything

Comment: So if the plan date is > the pay date that has an X, pull in the amount?  Not sure I follow the logic rule you need.  You likely will benefit from the cell function hlookup.  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/hlookup.php

Comment: Yeah I'm with Alan on this, an Hlookup or an Index/Match would be what I'd use, but I'm not entirely sure I'm following

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to accomplish correctly, your dates on the first worksheet (E3, F3, etc) need to be changed to Thursday dates - they are Wed dates right now.Also, you need the descriptions in column B of the first sheet to exactly match the descriptions in column A of the second sheet. This is why accountants like to use account numbers instead of account descriptions when possible.
If you change those here are your formulas:

Second sheet cell A2 - =IF(WEEKDAY(A3)<=5,A3+5-WEEKDAY(A3),A3-WEEKDAY(A3)+7+5). This checks the day of week of the current date then adds days as needed. It seems like there might be an easier way to get this.

Second sheet cells B6, B7, B8, B10 ,etc = =IF(HLOOKUP(A10,$F$4:$J$8,MATCH(A12,$D$5:$D$8,0)+1,FALSE)="x",VLOOKUP(A12,$D$5:$E$8,2,FALSE),""), The hlookup determines if there is an "x" in the current week and the vlookup pulls the amount from the correct line.

[image]